# Как в Laravel обновить запись в таблице, если некоторые ячейки массива данных могут быть пустыми?

Tags: php, laravel

На странице настроек профиля пользователь может заполнить/изменить несколько, а может и всего лишь одно поле. При этом массив $request может содержать пустые ячейки. И команда

```
$user->update($request-all());
```

не сработает или обнулит значения в некоторых колонках. Понятно, что можно перебрать массив и выкинуть пустые значения, но тогда придется указывать в методе update все заполняемые поля.
Есть в eloquent ORM инструментарий, который сам все сделает, чтобы не городить много кода?

Comment: Чего? У вас есть данные, которые вы берете из БД. Пользователь редактирует эти данные и отправляет обратно в БД. Если пользователь отправляет пустые данные, то почему в БД должно быть что то другое?

Comment: Например, если он не меняет город, то отправляется пустой city_id

Comment: А почему он у вас пустой отправляется? Над этим подумайте лучше.